# Formatting sandbox

Tags: support, design

Feel free to do your tests here.

Comment: Why is this needed if there's a live preview anyway?

Comment: @oak: to discuss issues [(example)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58760/kbd-yes-still-kbd-doesnt-play-nice-with-lists)

Comment: There's no live preview for Commenting though. I didn't realize you could make inline links in comments for a while because using the footnote syntax didn't work in comments.

Comment: @Fallen yeah, commenting formatting could be better, you can use this question however to try things out. By the way, usually padding with spaces helps.

Comment: ‮I'm trying out my new keyboard.  Is it working?

Comment: Θ or ϴ or θ or  ϑ

Comment: 5657ghjghjgjghjhgjhgj

Answer (score 9):

You need to define a [`burrow`](http://df.magmawiki.com/index.php/Burrow) for the safe zone, and a civilian [`alert`](http://df.magmawiki.com/index.php/DF2010:Alerts) that restricts movement to it.

- To create the burrow

  - Press <kbd>w</kbd> to go to the burrows screen
  - Press <kbd>a</kbd> to add a new burrow
  - Size the burrow (remember, a  burrow is 3d)
  - Choose a name, color, etc
- To create a new alert

  - Press <kbd>m</kbd> to go to the military screen
  - Press <kbd>a</kbd> to go to the alerts screen
  - Press <kbd>c</kbd> to create a new alert
  - Name it with <kbd>N</kbd>
  - Change the burrow restriction by pressing enter on the burrow while the burrow is highlighted.
- To activate the alert (as the civilian alert)

  - Press <kbd>enter</kbd> while the alert is highlighted.

---

- See also:

  - [Military Interface](http://df.magmawiki.com/index.php/DF2010:Military_interface)
  - [Scheduling](http://df.magmawiki.com/index.php/Scheduling)

Comment: [Original answer by C. Ross](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3597/how-to-get-your-dwarfs-inside/3602#3602)

Comment: TAKE THIS, @BADP! And you can probably answer George's inquiry.

Answer (score 5):

Community wiki? I don't need no stinkin' community wiki.

Comment: 'Removing wiki' on an answer if the question is CW is a no-op.

Comment: @badp ...and now it isn't.

Comment: why no community wiki?

Answer (score 5):

Comment: Y u no include narwhals? :,(

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Some testing on [how things work](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).
Does it work here yet? Is there [support](/questions/tagged/support) on Gaming for awesome tags?</kbd>

> ! This should
>   ! Ultimately fail.
>   However... 
>   ! What about 
>   ! 
>   ! If I do it like this?
>   Notice the requirement of either whitespace (specifically, **two spaces at the end of the text on a line**) or a literal `<br>` to force the line break.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Keyboard]

<kbd>Esc</kbd>  <kbd>F1</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd>  <kbd>F5</kbd><kbd>F6</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd>   <kbd>F9</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd>
<kbd><sub>`</sub><sup>~</sup></kbd>   <kbd><sub>1</sub><sup>!</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>2</sub><sup>@</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>3</sub><sup>#</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>4</sub><sup>$</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>5</sub><sup>%</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>6</sub><sup>^</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>7</sub><sup>&</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>8</sub><sup>*</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>9</sub><sup>(</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>0</sub><sup>)</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>-</sub><sup>_</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>=</sub><sup>+</sup></kbd><kbd><- Backspace</kbd>
<kbd>Tab</kbd>    <kbd>Q</kbd>  <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd>  <kbd>T</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>O</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd><kbd><sub>[</sub><sup>{</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>]</sub><sup>}</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>\</sub><sup>|</sup></kbd>                 
<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd> <kbd><sub>;</sub><sup>:</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>'</sub><sup>"</sup></kbd><kbd>↵ Enter</kbd>            
<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>           <kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>C</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd> <kbd><sub>,</sub><sup><</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>.</sub><sup>></sup></kbd><kbd><sub>/</sub><sup>?</sup></kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>                  

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>         <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>                                           <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>????</kbd>     <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

Soruced from [Anime and Manga.SE's Formatting Sandbox](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/873/1587)

Answer (score 3):

## Image resizing

[image: normal]
[image: huge]
[image: large]
[image: medium]
[image: small]
[image: bigsquare]
[image: smallsquare]

Comment: thanks for this thing, didn't know it was possible!

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Chupa chups brownie croissant. Icing tiramisu gummi bears cookie. Croissant cookie cake donut soufflé gummies fruitcake macaroon. Brownie gummi bears jelly-o carrot cake. Pie caramels chocolate bar. Halvah cheesecake sweet roll donut powder gummies. Cheesecake cookie cotton candy gummies cupcake. Cookie lollipop marshmallow cheesecake. Toffee jelly jelly-o. Sweet gingerbread soufflé gummies fruitcake halvah chocolate cake bonbon. Jelly-o halvah croissant gingerbread jelly beans marshmallow oat cake chupa chups. Cotton candy faworki brownie candy bonbon muffin carrot cake chupa chups. Pudding cheesecake carrot cake lollipop wafer pie apple pie icing. 
Toffee brownie toffee ice cream gummi bears icing soufflé topping lemon drops. Chocolate bar gummies gingerbread halvah biscuit. Icing candy sweet roll jelly-o danish sweet roll pudding apple pie muffin. Wypas cookie candy canes gummi bears marzipan. Lollipop candy donut halvah dessert wafer. Marzipan sugar plum toffee pie. Bear claw liquorice apple pie icing powder sweet roll powder. Caramels lemon drops faworki sesame snaps pastry pastry toffee. Chupa chups danish cookie tiramisu tart bonbon donut pastry jelly. Gingerbread ice cream caramels. Donut croissant biscuit donut lollipop fruitcake powder donut oat cake. Pudding chocolate cake icing sweet biscuit cookie. Marzipan donut tart powder topping.</kbd>

Comment: now I'm hungry...

Comment: Mmmm... Pastry.

Comment: It reminds of Internet Explorer during the early 2000's & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>#  ❢
[Malicious Link!](http://gam%D1%96ng.stackexchange.com)</kbd>

> spoiler 1
> spoiler 2 after 2 `<br>`'s after spoiler 1
> spoiler 3 after 4 `<br>`'s after spoiler 2

Comment: iiiiiiiiiiiiiii

Comment: @badp Do you think that's by design or by accident?

Comment: I think it can go both ways.

Answer (score 1):

TAKE THIS, @BADP! And you can probably answer George's inquiry.

Comment: Just to test it... a comment.

Comment: I'm a wiki rebel.&nbsp;Not really.

Comment: &#160; &#xa0; &nbsp; &#8232;                                                    Hi!

Comment: <deleted>asavsdasdasfasdasdvasdg

Comment: adasdlasdDELETED

Comment: aDELETEDSADAsdfsdf

Comment: dEleted afdsdfasddasgsa coconut

Comment: asdalsdajsdlaksdlkasdalskadslkjaslsdfhlkasdfhklasdfhkasdfhklasdfhklasdfklasdf

Comment: @galacticninja akdjwinsjsksj jwhsuwjj wijdwjiwjdj kookaijsbden kahekddhe?

Answer (score 1):

You can jump down ledges, but you can't climb back up them. Here is an example:

<kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd>Ledge A</kbd>   Ledge B</kbd>     Ledge C</kbd>  Ledge D</kbd>

You can jump from Ledge A to Ledge B, then to C and D, but you can't jump from Ledge C to Ledge B.

Comment: Boing, __wheee!__ Boing, __wheee!__ Wait, I no can get up? NOO!

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 1):

**S**omehow Th**i**s isn't Bold except I write with a **S** **p** ace inbetween

this is **W**eird

Comment: ---strikeout---

Answer (score 1):

Testing something related to edits & mod stuff

Testing some mod features nothing to see here...

1800 999 999

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Link</kbd>

<kbd>Blah blah</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

> This is a Spoiler, **This is a Bold Spoiler**
>
> ## This is a H1 Spoiler
>
> *This is an Italic Spoiler* 
>  Spoilerception (doesn't work)

Answer (score 0):

| Parameter | Details |
| --- | --- |
| < | Opens a file for read operations |
| > | Opens a file for write operations. The existing file will be overwritten |
| >> | Opens a file for append operations. New lines will be appended to an existing file |

Answer (score 0):

> ! spoiler 1
>
> ! spoiler 2 after pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice after spoiler 1
>
> ! spoiler 3 after pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> four times after spoiler 2

non spoiler break

> spoiler 1
> spoiler 2 after 2 `<br>`'s after spoiler 1
> spoiler 3 after 4 `<br>`'s after spoiler 2

^ all on one line

> <kbd>kbd in a spoiler</kbd> <kbd>`formatted kbd text in a spoiler`</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

> Test **test** test

```
Test **test** test
```

> Test **test** test

Answer (score 0):

Testing preview vs render for science. Hit 'edit' to view the preview

- **With URL Encoding**:
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_video_games
- **No URL Encoding**:
  [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Pokémon_video_games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_video_games)

Answer (score 0):

These are the failed reuploads at the time Glorfindel's script ran in Arqade (URLs and failure info are from the [results of Glorfindel’s script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Glorfindel83/SE-Userscripts/master/upload-imgur-images.md)). (Made Community wiki so anyone can edit.)

"Fixed" on the "Notes" column means that the media has been converted to be ≤ 2 MiB and/or converted to a compatible format with SE Imgur, and that it has been reuploaded and edited into its associated post(s).

The "URL" column leads to the post(s) associated with the media file by linking to the [search results in Arqade of the following query format](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2Fexample.gif%22): `url:"https://i.imgur.com/example.gif"`.

---

Some notes on converting:

- For quick conversion, you can use [XnShell](https://www.xnview.com/en/xnshell/) (Windows only): it adds a few neat Shell Extension (right-click file menu) options.
- JPGs > 2 MiB can be made ≤ 2 MiB by saving them at a lower quality. Some image editing software, such as Irfanview, have a 'set file size' functionality. Setting it at 2048 KiB (= 2 MiB) should work.
- PNGs > 2 MiB can usually be made ≤ 2 MiB by saving them to JPG. Quality = 95 usually works.
- Imgur GIFV videos also have a GIF version in a similar URL pattern. E.g., https://i.imgur.com/example.gifv → https://i.imgur.com/example.gif
- GIFs > 2 MiB are a bit trickier to edit. Using a GIF optimizer such as [this one](https://ezgif.com/optimize), it may be possible to lessen its filesize to ≤ 2 MiB by doing one or more of the following: resizing it to have lower resolution (SE only shows 650px max width on embedded images), cutting its frames in half by removing every 2nd frame then slowing it down to 50% to get back to previous speed, color reduction + dither to reduce colors to 128, and lossy GIF compression (may lower quality significantly, depending on image and compression level).
- Another alternative is to archive the post using services such as: [Internet Archive Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/) and [archive.today](https://archive.is/), so that the images in it can be edited back later. Note that this will only archive the image if it is embedded into the post. If it is linked but not embedded into the post you will need to archive the original Imgur URL, e.g., `https://i.imgur.com/example.gif`.

---

| URL | Failure | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/uWGyyGA.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/uWGyyGA.jpg%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | fixed |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/1UxRivS.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/1UxRivS.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | fixed |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/1qeWOKe.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/1qeWOKe.gif%22) | JSONException: org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1] |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/2zx7X9o](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/2zx7X9o) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. | fixed |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/3kgjmV8.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/3kgjmV8.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | fixed |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/454sD1R.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/454sD1R.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/4y4F9H7.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/4y4F9H7.jpg%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/5PN0Xib.gifv"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/5PN0Xib.gifv%22) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/62c1aGg.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/62c1aGg.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/64nvqLx.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/64nvqLx.jpg%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/6LUS7Ik.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/6LUS7Ik.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/6eSKe0y.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/6eSKe0y.jpg%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/7t6pCKz.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/7t6pCKz.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | fixed |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/8rd2q.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/8rd2q.png%22) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/92aaYAI](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/92aaYAI) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. | fixed |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/98CMlvh.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/98CMlvh.png%22) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/9fKKrtv.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/9fKKrtv.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/358979/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/9nHlTfv.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/9nHlTfv.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | fixed |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/9vvFrz4.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/9vvFrz4.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/183546/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/9xM0jOh.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/9xM0jOh.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/209310/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/BJHA7pF.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/BJHA7pF.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/BQtkflp.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/BQtkflp.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/C2Vb7hs.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/C2Vb7hs.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/D6J1P4I.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/D6J1P4I.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/DtvRobI.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/DtvRobI.jpg%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/EXrJifP.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/EXrJifP.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/EkULFSp.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/EkULFSp.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/FMjcDBt.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/FMjcDBt.jpg%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/GmQdQxm.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/GmQdQxm.jpg%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/GmZYsiX.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/GmZYsiX.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/GrlkyNi.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/GrlkyNi.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/HEkvZmY.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/HEkvZmY.jpg%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/HRgupVM.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/HRgupVM.jpg%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/JE7cP.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/JE7cP.jpg%22) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/L0F6k.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/L0F6k.png%22) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/MNNBo5l.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/MNNBo5l.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/NI7zcse.gifv"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/NI7zcse.gifv%22) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/OQ5w7DN.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/OQ5w7DN.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/OkX229e.gifv"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/OkX229e.gifv%22) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/On21DHS.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/On21DHS.jpg%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/PiqW7.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/PiqW7.jpg%22) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/PuvvUPU.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/PuvvUPU.jpg%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/QF86DfH.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/QF86DfH.jpg%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/Qki1dyw.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/Qki1dyw.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/QsxScn1.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/QsxScn1.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/Rfnh2cu.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/Rfnh2cu.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/T2B3xUM.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/T2B3xUM.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/TfXRbuI.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/TfXRbuI.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/VyXmBQK.png?1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/VyXmBQK.png?1) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/Wm0FuXj.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/Wm0FuXj.jpg%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/XIR5V9M.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/XIR5V9M.png%22) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/XbF4iYc.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/XbF4iYc.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/XyLef0I.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/XyLef0I.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | fixed |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/YDQYG0b.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/YDQYG0b.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/YjzBjqF.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/YjzBjqF.jpg%22) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/ZeC7VQO.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/ZeC7VQO.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/aD7eICO.gifv"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/aD7eICO.gifv%22) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/aQJfAQN.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/aQJfAQN.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | fixed |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/boPtDzn.gifv"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/boPtDzn.gifv%22) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/cvYGIMc.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/cvYGIMc.png%22) | APIException: Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/d7FSfN3.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/d7FSfN3.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/dGwpTfn.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/dGwpTfn.jpg%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/dhApZMS.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/dhApZMS.jpg%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/diBLluQ.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/diBLluQ.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/e1zkciM.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/e1zkciM.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/e8aFHXw.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/e8aFHXw.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/ekV1B2F.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/ekV1B2F.jpg%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/ezS0s2p.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/ezS0s2p.gif%22) | JSONException: org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1] |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/f4olc2o.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/f4olc2o.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/fU1HGV1.webm](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/fU1HGV1.webm) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/fkDAP5h.jpg?1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/fkDAP5h.jpg?1) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/gRd4wwp.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/gRd4wwp.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/h5toazj.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/h5toazj.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/hfewv2T.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/hfewv2T.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/hj5yFCS.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/hj5yFCS.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/iTrJwYq.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/iTrJwYq.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/j3JvvdB.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/j3JvvdB.jpg%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/jGdNBfk.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/jGdNBfk.jpg%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/jRs4JAN.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/jRs4JAN.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/jcIPYvq.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/jcIPYvq.jpg%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/jxGR4Ii.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/jxGR4Ii.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/kaNzBeR.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/kaNzBeR.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/kpHbPCH.mp4"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/kpHbPCH.mp4%22) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/l4MUE4Z.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/l4MUE4Z.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | fixed |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/lQ7ReJe](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/lQ7ReJe) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. | fixed |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/mi2eDmA.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/mi2eDmA.jpg%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/nEgGMDp.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/nEgGMDp.jpg%22) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/pf6zCZX.gifv"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/pf6zCZX.gifv%22) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/ruPmpaq.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/ruPmpaq.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/scGMdg8.jpg?1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/scGMdg8.jpg?1) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/uIBdHue.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/uIBdHue.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/uffL0kg.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/uffL0kg.png%22) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/v7xIlJX.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/v7xIlJX.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/xGd89bn.gifv"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/xGd89bn.gifv%22) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. | fixed |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/xU2FUxk.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/xU2FUxk.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/xVNsn1F.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/xVNsn1F.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/y1fORtV.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/y1fORtV.png%22) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/y3IpRf8.png?1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/y3IpRf8.png?1) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/z53TGQs.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/z53TGQs.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | fixed |

Answer (score 0):

Does this thing work?

[image: profile for noobprogrammer on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

Guess it does.