# Console controller button images instead of <kbd> used mainly for PC keys

Tags: feature-request, design

Consider [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/36012/23901) as an illustration of how awkward the rectangular `<kbd>`-tagged keys look as console controller button:

> [image]

And compare with this mockup of controller button images:

> [image]

Each button image could be added to the site's [sprite sheet](http://cdn.sstatic.net/gaming/img/sprites.png?v=2), which has a ton of unused space. Special "insert controller button" menu could be added to post editing bar. They could have a syntax like `[key-xbox:A]` and `[key-ps:x]`.

Other SE sites have their own special features, why not add this handy thing for Arqade?

Comment: Well, for one, we're Arqade.  And another, sounds like a ton of work for little benefit.  It doesn't really add much functionality.  And you missed the Wii/U.

Comment: Don't forget the Ouya. And the N64. And the Genesis. And the...

Comment: @Frank Sounds like similar reasons to not have lazers. Are you saying you don't like the Lazer Mothership?

Comment: @RavenDreamer Lazers is a straight up image change.  No big deal.  What's being asked for here is...slightly more complicated than that, especially for the custom markdown.  And I don't think it really offers anything of value.

Comment: Sure, what I described is a bit difficult to do. Not very difficult, but considerably so. I don't know much about much, so I assume some of the more tech-savvy people who actually do this kind of stuff could come up with a much easier way to implement these icons, so don't take my rough sketch as a "do it or drop it" proposition. It's just how I, from far away, saw this could be done, in theory.

Comment: Well then, I'd be happy if someone could shop up all the buttons and post that as an answer so I could accept it. My photoshop skills are way below publicly acceptable level.

Comment: See also http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/316/images-for-controller-buttons-and-keyboard-keys/319#319

Comment: @badp guess what? They look like crap. Even Steam has implemented a "smiley" button into their chat to paste terribly visible unicode chars. This isn't a desired solution at all.

Comment: @badp I would suggest [this answer](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/422/42984) as a better alternative for the console buttons.

Comment: @Batophobia [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mZC5q.png) is intolerable. Even if the [font smoothing is on](http://i.stack.imgur.com/b6lGi.png). I mean, circled characters maaaybe, but look at those pathetic excuses of arrows. No way.

Comment: Perhaps you prefer [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/aljNi.png) for A and [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/aljNi.png) for B.

Comment: @Batophobia those are the same links.

Comment: Yes, on a NES controller A and B look the same.

Answer (score 5):

For some reason, we have been stuck with (jjj) these not-great-looking kbd tags that just don't work well in most contexts, such as when used <kbd>inline</kbd> (notice how their baseline is lower than normal text and how those j's and this line right here, look, hit the box) or [inside lists](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/717/23).

[Some people think this is, after all, okay.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58760/13992) I don't agree with these people, but I'd rather not make the problem even worse through javascript hacks.

Besides - what if we need to tell people to press the <kbd>A</kbd> button on their keyboard?

I think the problem is that it's not just awkward to use `kbd` for console buttons. It's awkward to use `kbd` period.

Even just these three small CSS tweaks would make things better:

```
padding: 1px 4px; /* instead of 2px 4px; also fixes baseline */
border-radius: 16px;
font-family: sans-serif;
```

> [image]

Comment: The [kbd tags on MSO](http://i.3ventic.eu/2014030711490678.png) look good imo and would fit here just fine.

Comment: @3ventic They'd look like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Lmmrh.png) (don't pay any mind to the links; I just imported the whole MSO css for that picture.)

Comment: I think something along these lines would be a pretty reasonable compromise. My biggest problem with the current `kbd` tags is that they're explicitly styled to look like PC keyboard keys, when those tags are often used for controller button inputs and other decidedly non-keyboard things. Since platform-specific images are probably not practical, this seems like a reasonable middle ground.

Comment: This would probably look fine if SE's UI designer paid us a visit.