# Markdown preview decodes URL characters, but the final post does not

Tags: bug, editing, markdown

When adding raw URLs to posts, the preview output differs from the final rendered result. Preview will decode any raw url into the actual characters, however, once posted, the URL decoding is not present.

You can use [this sandbox post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14622/28182) to view the difference.

#### Preview

[image: Preview]

#### Result once posted

[image: Final Render]